# Ошибка "Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()" при установленном php5-curl

Tags: curl, php, ubuntu

```
# php -m |grep curl
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/curl.so' - /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /usr/lib/php5/20090626/curl.so) in Unknown on line 0
```

Переустанавливал все что, связано с curl`ом. Ничего не помогло :( Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5 openssl php5-curl` делали?

Comment: да. несколько раз. Удалял, устанавливал...

Comment: Выполните 
    ls -l /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/curl.so

если нет исполняемого файла, попробуйте скопилировать из исходников.

Answer (score 5):

`php.ini` раскомментируй расширение библиотеки

Небольшие пояснения. В подобной ошибке у себя пришел к тому что стоит убрать точку с запятой из строки

```
; extension=php_curl.dll
```

то есть

1. проверяем если установлена библиотека curl
2. настраиваем php.ini раскомментировав строку, которая выше

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install php5-curl
php5enmod curl
service apache restart
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас не совпадение версий. Биндинг заточен под более новую версию libcurl, чем та, которая у вас установлена.
Можно либо поискать более свежую библиотеку libcurl в репозиториях (ну или собрать https://curl.haxx.se/download.html),
либо пересобрать php-curl, что будет сложнее: [pecl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/install.html)